# How to use reduce to sum lists in a map

Tags: scala

I have generated a map in the following type

```
immutable.Map[Int,List[Double]]

Map(
1 -> List(1.02),
2 -> List(0.42, 6.88))
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to access the List() in my map and use reduce to sum the elements.

```
myMap.reduce(???)
```

Comment: have you read the basics of using `Map`, such as accessing values? I recommend starting there. If you have, what in the instructions would you like help understanding?

Comment: I know i can access individual keys myMap.(1).reduce(_ + _)  But what about going through the entire map and converting the List[] into a Double representing the sum? For example, the new map would be Map[Int, Double]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate a Map using the `.map()` function.  Each iteration you will get a key and value, and you need to return a key and a value.  In your case the `key` will be one of your Integers (`1`, `2`) and we can just pass that straight through.  The `value` will be a List of Doubles, which we can sum using the built in `.sum`:

```
myMap.map { case (key, value) => (key, value.sum) }
```

Example:

```
scala> val myMap = Map(1 -> List(1.02), 2 -> List(0.42, 6.88))
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Double]] = Map(1 -> List(1.02), 2 -> List(0.42, 6.88))

scala> myMap.map { case (key, value) => (key, value.sum) } 
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(1 -> 1.02, 2 -> 7.3)
```

---

You can replace `.sum` with `.reduce(_ + _)` and get the same answer.

Comment: thanks, is there is performance difference if I use value.reduce(_ + _) to sum up the the values in the list?

Comment: @ext2008: What performance difference did you measure when you tried it?